# Recover dropped Stashed Changes in Github Desktop (Windows 10)

Tags: git, github, git-stash, github-desktop

Using Github Desktop (v. 2.9.6 on Windows 10) as beginner, when moving back and forth from branch to branch, I stash my changes to keep them on a branch for later. But doing this twice in a row, instead of stacking the changes in the stash, it actually overwrites and drops the previous stash.

I have therefore lost multiple changes. Github desktop does not offer an option to recover these, although they should be recoverable using command lines (see here: [How to recover a dropped stash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/how-to-recover-a-dropped-stash-in-git)). But a Shell command line is no longer readily available in Github desktop. Also the discarded files were not available in the windows Recycle Bin, and trying to cancel using ctrl+Z didn't help.

This question is also similar to thread [How can I undo discard changes in GitHub Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546133/how-can-i-undo-discard-changes-in-github-desktop), but the thread is closed without satisfactory answer. Accepted solution simply says that Github desktop staff confirmed there is no way to recover such discarded changes.

Comment: If you're on macOS, use `terminal` as your command line. If you're on Windows, use `Powershell`. Then try the stuff in the question you linked

Answer (score 13):

A Stash dropped in Github Desktop on Windows 10 can be recovered in the following way:

1. Find the $stash_hash address of the dropped stash in the Logs of Github Desktop:

- Visit this folder: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\GitHub Desktop\logs
- Open the log file of the day stash drop happened.
- Locate the line that says "Dropped stash", it contains the hash address (in my case 92de3e8c594356cf04169d68e9cdf634806ab315). See [Screenshot from Github Desktop Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPLgX.png)

2. Enable Windows Command Prompt to seamlessly write Git command using the same git.exe as Github Desktop. The following thread explains it all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70441638/4074517
3. In Windows Command Prompt, navigate to the folder containing your repository and enter the following command:
   "git checkout -b recovery $stash_hash" where $stash_hash is the hash address of the dropped stash. This will create a new branch called "recovery" in the repository where all previously dropped stashed changes are committed. This is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/91795/4074517

Comment: The folder on macOS is `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/GitHub Desktop/logs`.

You can also use the `Help` tab in the menu bar and click on the `Show logs in Finder` option.

Comment: You are a life saver. I didn't realize that stashes aren't all saved separately, and will get lost once used.