# Can I undo the deletion of my untracked git files? Githubdesktop

Tags: github-desktop

1. I installed GitHub Desktop and added a local repository of my
   existing git repo.
2. I selected all of the files that I didn't want to track > right
   clicked > add to ignore list.
3. I pushed the changes

**When I went back into my repo it had deleted all of my untracked files and left only what was committed. Is there anyway to undo this?**

I had never committed my untracked files before so they are not on github

I had used tortoise git previously before switching to GitHub Desktop. I wouldn't be surprised if I did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to solve this by applying the stash that was dropped from github desktop.

This answer and the links in this answer helped me solve it:

[recover dropped stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442218/2285215)

Once checking the github dekstop log for the dropped stash hash I simply ran the command

`git stash apply $stash_hash`